# 'any-pointer' and 'any-hover' Media Queries

Tags: css, media-queries

How use these two options ?

in deskop browser :

```
@media(any-hover){
    body{
        color:red;
    }
}
@media(any-pointer){
    body{
        color:green;
    }
}
```

all text is green . Why ? 
I thought that in touch devices text was green and desctop browser was red

Answer (score 2):

@18zehn was close. The reason your text is always green is because the any-pointer is last, and CSS evaluates same-specificity from top to bottom, giving precedence to later rules.  Also, touch counts as a coarse pointer, so it will always be green.

Flip the media queries. Touch as your only input doesn't have hover (unless the device can detect hovering of your finger), so the any-hover below any-pointer will not apply (as desired). This will give you what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Any-Pointer is used to check, whether the Device has a input device that supports pointers. I guess your desktop has such a device, i.e. your mouse.

So this condition is true and your text is green.

Any-hover is used to check, if your device supports hover.

So both conditions work on your desktop. None will work on a smartphone.